# kern.log and syslog grow 40+ GB in few minutes

Tags: release-hera

I've read most of the answers and nothing really seems to be related to case except force shut down and cleaning up `kern.log` and `syslog` files manually on next boot. Happened a few times already. I've tried to take a sample of 20000 lines from `kern.log`(which is almost 40GB) and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGIrtAJCrV_Ru94QLK-5x58F1mBoaxQo/view?usp=sharing). While running below script:

```
for log in test;  
  echo "${log} :"
  sed -e 's/\[[^]]\+\]//' -e 's/.*[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}//' ${log} \
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -hr | head -10
done
```

I get the following lines:

```
 559  npc kernel:   worker_thread+0x34/0x410
    559  npc kernel:  wlp5s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
    559  npc kernel:  WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 19976 at /build/linux-hwe-pGQy9q/linux-hwe-5.3.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_sta_state+0x165/0x400 [mac80211]
    559  npc kernel:   sta_info_move_state+0x284/0x360 [mac80211]
    559  npc kernel:   __sta_info_flush+0x139/0x1b0 [mac80211]
    559  npc kernel:   __sta_info_destroy_part2+0x36/0x1a0 [mac80211]
    559  npc kernel:   ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
    559  npc kernel:   ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1e/0x20
    559  npc kernel:   ? process_one_work+0x3f0/0x3f0
    559  npc kernel:   process_one_work+0x1fd/0x3f0
```

My system details:

```
OS: elementary OS Hera 5.1.5
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz
DISK: 150GB SSD (partition-dual boot w/ windows10)
```

Additional WLAN related hwinfo, which could be relevant:

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: wlp5s0
                version: 78
                serial: 48:a4:72:xx:xx:xx
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-59-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.43.85 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:132 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
```

When it happens, suddenly the CPU is at 30-40%, and the next thing I know that no space on deceive left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using hwe kernel. Can you remove it together with headers and then update the grub and also initramfs?

Comment: Thanks. Done that but now it's trying to install ```linux-headers-4.15.0-106 linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic linux-image-4.15.0-106-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-106-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-106-generic```. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes. Then you can upgrade the kernel to newer version. And also remember to install xorg. sudo apt install xorg After you remove the hwe kernel.

Comment: Guide: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/08/upgrade-ubuntu18-04-3-kernel-5-0-xorg/

Comment: Kernel upgrade: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/

Comment: You can actually choose which kernel is the newest. Anyway I remember that 5.0.4 is probably the newest for Elementary OS. I do not remember how to check what is the latest stable kernel for the exact distro. I know that there isna command which let to check this. But I forgot this. Will look for later.

Comment: Here is 5.5 kernel. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-kernel-5-5-ubuntu/

Comment: Elementary OS is Ubuntu / Debian based. Even kernels from kernel.org work. I am using 5.7 kernel in my Elementary OS Hera.

Comment: Thank you @Sysadmin. I will try to install a new kernel this weekend and report back.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Sysadmin. Updating kernel solved my issue. I've used https://github.com/bkw777/mainline to easily update it from ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0):

**How to upgrade Elementary OS to the 5.7.0 kernel.**

**Install necessary packages**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncurses-dev bison flex libssl-dev libelf-dev
```

**To check hardware**

```
sudo lspci
```

**To check missing firmware**

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This step is important, because it shows missing firmware.

**Make directories for firmware**

```
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/kernel
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/i915
mkdir /home/username/Downloads/rtl
```

**To get rid of missing firmware errors for amdgpu**

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/amdgpu
wget https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/files/4124959/firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
unzip firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb.zip
sudo dpkg -i firmware-radeon-ucode-rock_2.110_all.deb
```

Or use eddy to install this deb

Source: https://github.com/M-Bab/linux-kernel-amdgpu-binaries/issues/82

**To get rid of missing firmware errors for i915**

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/i915
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp -R /linux-firmware/i915/* /lib/firmware/i915/
```

**To get rid of missing firmware errors for rtl (Realtek LAN and Wi-Fi adapters in my DELL)**

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/rtl
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
sudo cp rtl8168fp-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic 
sudo cp rtl8125a-3.fw /lib/firmware/rtl_nic
```

**Download kernel 5.7.0**

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/kernel
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.7.tar.xz
tar -xf linux-5.7.tar.xz
cd linux-5.7
cp -v /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
make menuconfig
```

save config and then exit.

**Use 4 core/thread - if your processor have 4 cores**

```
make -j 4
```

**Use 8 core/thread - if your processor have 8 cores**

```
make -j 8
```

Then type below commands:

```
sudo make modules_install 
sudo make install 
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.7.0
```

**ignore these errors below, just because those three bin files are not made yet**
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_dmcu.bin for module amdgpu

Type in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
uname -mrs
```

**To check errors after reboot:**

```
sudo journalctl -b
sudo dmesg
```

Answer (score 0):

List below file:

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

should contain this:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
            /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}

/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
{
    rotate 4
    weekly
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
            /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
```

If it does not contain the above , edit it and replace

```
sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

Then force the logrotate manually:

```
sudo logrotate --force  /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

If it will show similar error:

> error: skipping "/var/log/syslog" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.

Then type in terminal:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/log/ && sudo chown root:root /var/log/
sudo chmod 755 /var && sudo chown root:root /var
sudo logrotate --force  /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way the bash script is wrong. Should be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for log in test; do
  echo "${log} :"
  sed -e 's/\[[^]]\+\]//' -e 's/.*[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}//' ${log} \
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -hr | head -10
done
```

I tested it, but have no idea what test in your case is.

Comment: test here is just the trimmed kern.log. And it works as I pasted it in terminal directly